# How to implement Next/Prev for modal Ajax popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bpopup

I'm using a bPopup jquery plugin to open ajax html files in the modal popup, but I want to extend it in order to go to the next slide in the modal without clicking out?

Here is the current code that I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.my-button').bind('click', function(e) {//select all the buttons with a class selector

        var loadFile = $(this).data("file");

        // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
        e.preventDefault();

        // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            contentContainer:'.content',
            loadUrl: loadFile //Uses jQuery.load()
        });
    });
});

<button data-file="test1.html" class="my-button">Load one modal</button>
<button data-file="test2.html" class="my-button">Load another modal</button>
<button data-file="test3.html" class="my-button">Load a third modal</button>
```

For example, if test1.html is open in the modal, and I want to go to test2.html within the open modal box without closing test1.html, and opening test2.html in another modal, is there a way to do this? I have tried adding  in the open modal, but it does trigger an event.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably save you a lot of time to just use something like **[Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)** since extending bPopup like you are trying to do will be probably be very buggy. With Fancybox, you can simply add a `rel` attribute to each of the modal links, and the `$.fancybox.next()` and `$.fancybox.prev()` will take you to the next/previous modal with that `rel`. Another alternative is [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) with similar functionality.